# Javascript - RegExp to match ANY number, including Infinity, negative numbers, and e+/- numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

So I need a RegExp in Javascript to check for any number:

```
2 -> true
3.14 -> true
2. -> true
.2 -> true
0 -> true
```

And it should also work for these:

```
Infinity -> true
-Infinity -> true
-0 -> true
-22 -> true
2e-3 -> true
5e-14 -> true
3e+2 -> true
8e2 -> true
```

The d will only allow positive integers, which is far from what i need to my RegExp, and I am not good at all with RegExps, so what's the most efficient RegExp to do this?

Comment: Why does it 'need' to be a regular expression?

Comment: @DavidThomas Because it's very easy to handle, and I am going to need this to replace stuff in strings..

Comment: Ofcourse your tried a few solutions yourself. Show them here, so maybe we can review your solutions

Comment: What do you mean by infinity? empty string?

Comment: @KooiInc I've tried this but I just don't know what's next: \d+\.?\d*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[-+]?(?:(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?|Infinity)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT5jO5/2)

Comment: ("2.").match(/[-+]?(?:(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?|Infinity)\b/g) Will return "2", not "2."

Comment: ok it is corrected now.